# How to save a music that is playing through radio?

Tags: music, audio, nokia-lumia-525, radio

While hearing music through radio in my Lumia 525 I tried to save it but didn't find an option to save a song that is playing in radio. How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **cannot** save songs played on radio service. It's a feature not available on WP (and probably on every mobile platform). Also, you cannot record the sound directly from the system, *i.e.* you are not allowed to record a song into a *.mp3* file.

What you **can** do? You can have the song recognised by an app, like [SoundHound](http://www.soundhound.com/) or [Shazam](http://www.shazam.com/). Personally, I'd recommend to you the second one, because it clearly [provides](https://support.shazam.com/hc/en-us/articles/202607506-Using-Shazam-with-Headphones) a way to check what song you are listening to. How? By using the phone mic to capture the sound from your earphones or speaker (not totally sure about the speaker). This way, you can check the songs aired on your radio station and then download them (even if I think that using Spotify would be better).

> Credits to this answer go to the people who commented on my former answer, improving it a lot.

Comment: I haven't checked this but does SoundHound or Shazam works(listens to the audio) when music is played from the same device??

Comment: @unomoinverde Thanks for your answer. Downloaded those two apps and I will try them.

Comment: Honestly I don't know whether this will work. But I think that if audio isn't stopped when one of those two apps work then it should be fine!

Comment: @uomoinverde it won't work for anti-piracy reasons.

Comment: Really? If true, then I'll edit the answer. But I think it's strange: if you can use Shazam to check songs played around, why can't you use it for music played by your own phone? I agree with you when it comes to save music on phone, but for music-checking, I find it a bit surprising.

Comment: I've already tried and it worked. I've just push the volume up and put the earphone near the microphone.

Comment: @NeilTurner Agree that record something from radio don't work but using those apps to discovery what song is works.

Comment: To clarify, an app can record via the mic but cannot record audio directly from the system (ie. radio, other music playback)

Comment: Then I'll edit my answer to insert all the information you gave in these comments (but first, let me have dinner ;-) )